# Can we use values in a listView to sum and display?

Tags: android, eclipse

in my application I have a table with three columns which is displayed in a list view. i want to add all values (int) in one column to show the total without accessing to the database. is it possible to show the total sum of the values in the listview. if possible can you please provide me a code to do that! thank you